# Passing "this" with bind returns undefined. Returning "this" returns windows object

Tags: javascript, dictionary, this

```
  class ObjectMapping {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
      map(func) {
        let b = func.bind(this)()
        console.log(b);
    }
  }
  
  const m = new ObjectMapping({ abc: 'abc',
      def: 'def' });
  const func = (value) => {
      return this[value]
  };
  
  m.map(func);
```

The `func` function is part of my assignment so it can't be changed but I can mess around with it to see what it returns.

```
const func = (value) => {
    return this //returns windows object
};
```

When I set it to just `this`, I get back the windows object regardless of what I pass in.

```
const func = (value) => {
    return value //returns undefined
};
```

When I bind it, it returns undefined.

```
map(func) {
   let key = Object.keys(this.value)[0] //key = abc
   let b = func(key)
   console.log(b);
}
const func = (value) => {
    return this.value
};
```

I tried passing in the the key but I still get undefined. How do I pass in an object and not get back the windows object?

Comment: Fat arrow functions does not have `this` binded

Comment: Don't use `.bind(this)()` - just use `.call(this)`.